# How to pass parameters to a thread in c multithreading properly

Tags: c, multithreading, parameters, pthreads

I'm trying to learn on C multithreading, and I've seen a couple of rare things.

I understand that passing parameters to a thread must be done with pointers. I've found an example which I don't understand. I'll copy the relevant lines:

```
pthread_t tid[MAX_THREADS]
int n_veg
pthread_create(&tid[n],NULL,caracter,(void *)n_veg)
```

caracter is obviously a predeclared function.

Now, why do we use a void pointer casting instead of a int pointer casting? Is there any relevant difference?

Secondly, why do we use a pointer casting in the first place? Can't we use "&n_veg" like with the first parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since both your questions are related, I'll answer them together: `pthread_create` takes a `void *` parameter, so you can really pass in any pointer you want. In this case though, we aren't actually passing a pointer, but just a simple integer value casted as a pointer. That means you will access it like this in `caracter`:

```
int value = (int)n_veg;
```

As you mentioned, you could very well pass an actual pointer as `&n_veg` and retrieve the value like this:

```
int value = *(int *)n_veg;
```

In fact, in most cases, you will need to pass more data than just an integer, such as a structure, and in that case, you *must* pass a pointer, as you can't simply cast it to a pointer like an integer.

One thing to keep in mind when you pass a pointer is that `n_veg` must not go out of scope as long as the thread is running. For example, if you do:

```
void test() {
  int n_veg;
  pthread_create(&tid[n],NULL,caracter,&n_veg);
}
```

then `&n_veg` will be invalid as soon as `test` returns, but the thread may still be running and will be holding an invalid address. Because of this, structures passed to threads are normally dynamically allocated, say using `malloc`, and the thread can `free` it once it has completed.

Comment: So, is there any real difference between passing a real pointer or casting the value if working with integers?

And, why *(int *)n_veg?

I'm sorry if that second question is stupid, it's my second year on programming and I had only used java until this week :/

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc: Yes there is. If you pass in a real pointer, you can change the original value using the pointer. About `*(int *)n_veg`: to use a `void *`, you need to cast to an actual type, hence the `(int *)`, and then the `*` dereferences the pointer to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_create` is defined as follows:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread, const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
     void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *restrict arg);
```

So it expects a `void *` as its last parameter. If you omit the cast, the compiler would give you a warning.

Comment: Oh, it's just that the method asks for it... I thought the void pointers were operated transparently to the method. Forget it.